# what to use before the word helping either "to" "in"

Tags: prepositions

> We are committed "to" helping survivors.
> We are committed "in" helping survivors.

Comment: I would say that we are committed to helping. I don't think I've ever heard anyone say that anyone was committed in doing something.

Answer (score 1):

It's less a question of being before "helping", than of being after "committed".
The phrase "commit to" is common. You can be committed to many things, including "helping survivors". It means about the same as "to promise to do something".

[Cambridge Dictionary "commit"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/commit?q=commit_1)

> commit to doing sth
> *Families who sign up to the service have to **commit to** buying their groceries from one internet source for a year.*